# how to determine a specific prime ideal splits or not in some large field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here I want to prove 3.3 (b),but I only know that $fg=2$ ($f$ is the residue class degree for $pO_F$ in $O_L$ and $g$ the number of $pO_F$ splits into),what other information can I acknowledge to deduce the assertion?

[image]

Comment: Hint: If p is inert in $L$ then $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)\cong\mathrm{Gal}(k_L/\mathbb F_p)$. Why is this impossible?

Comment: I see,but is there any general conclusion about the isomorphism?I haven't seen it in my textbook.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you unsure about why there is an isomorphism of Galois groups, or of how that helps?

Comment: Yes,I confuse about the isomorphism.I can show there is an induced map from $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$ to $\mathrm{Gal}(k_L/\mathbb F_p)$,and they have same orders,what to do next?

Comment: The latter group is cyclic. But you’ve shown that the first group isn’t.

Comment: I mean how to show the two groups are isomorphism.

Comment: The map you’ve constructed should be surjective by definition.